# Change the dropdown value by clicking the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, href

```
<apex:selectList value="{!operator}" size="1" id="operator123" >
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="=" itemLabel="Equal" id="teja123" />
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="!=" itemLabel="Not Equal To"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="<=" itemLabel="Less Or Equal"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue=">=" itemLabel="Greater Or Equal"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue=">" itemLabel="Greater Than"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="<" itemLabel="Less Than"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Like" itemLabel="Like"/>
        </apex:selectList>

<b><a href="#" onClick="clearValue()" > New Search </a> </b>
```

by click the new search i want change the dropdown value to equal

I have tried this way ,but it is not working

```
<script>
function clearValue() {
document.getElementById('{!$Component.page1:form1:operator123:teja123}').value='equal';
}           
</script>
```

Comment: where is your js function? Post it too?

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: No .i am not much into java script .but i am expecting answer in the way some event happened action has to be done

Comment: hi any answers think as a html dropdown and javascriprt  and send me the logic and i will convert it

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you should use "=" instead of "equal"

```
function clearValue() {         
document.getElementById("operator123").value = "=";
}
```